# BadTokenException even on Activity's Context

Tags: android

I have initialized progressDialog with Activity's context as suggested and still app crashes a lot with "BadTokenException error".

Error log:

`02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548): Process: com.xyz.abx.app, PID: 17548
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@1494d8e8 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at com.payumoney.appower.app.PaymentWebView$2.onPageStarted(PaymentWebView.java:86)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:484)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:107)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-14 21:20:40.318: E/AndroidRuntime(17548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)`

Crash occurs here:

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
                if (!progress.isShowing()&PaymentWebView.class!=null)           {
                    progress.show();
                }
        }
```

and initializationin the oncreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_web_view);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Please wait");

    mWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.paymentWebView);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

`

I have also used Activity.this and getapplicationcontext without any result. Please suggest what might be crashing with badtokenexception on progressdialog when context is ok.enter code here

Comment: see this.. it may be the cause.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10446316/1263362

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys the following worked for me:

```
@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
            if (!progress.isShowing()&PaymentWebView.class!=null&!isFinishing)           {
                progress.show();
            }
    }
```

if(!isFinishing) condition prevents .show() from executing, when for any reason object of the Activity losses the context. I will also update this if I find out why context was being lost when activity was in foreground and user was interacting with webview.

Net outcome: at some pages while navigating in the webview progressdialog is not shown.(I think a crash occured at this point earlier)

see : [Android : BadTokenException when I want to show a progresssDialog a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921049/android-badtokenexception-when-i-want-to-show-a-progresssdialog-a-second-time)

Answer (score 0):

Move your dialog logic to the onResume method of your activity, when onCreate is called the activity is not yet running and will cause a badtokenexception.

Hope that helps.